# Regarding Silverlight and prism

Tags: silverlight, prism

i am developing a sample using silverlight5 and prism4. When i run my application i am getting th following exception

"Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'System.Exception.get_InnerException()'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden."

and the stack trace is as follows

at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.PartManager.TryOnComposed()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.TrySatisfyImportsStateMachine(PartManager partManager, ComposablePart part)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.TrySatisfyImports(PartManager partManager, ComposablePart part, Boolean shouldTrackImports)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.SatisfyImports(ComposablePart part)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ComposablePartExportProvider.<>c_*DisplayClass2.b*_0()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionServices.TryInvoke(Action action)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ComposablePartExportProvider.Compose(CompositionBatch batch)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionContainer.Compose(CompositionBatch batch)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.AttributedModelServices.ComposeExportedValue[T](CompositionContainer container, T exportedValue)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.MefBootstrapper.RegisterBootstrapperProvidedTypes()
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.MefBootstrapper.ConfigureContainer()
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.MefBootstrapper.Run(Boolean runWithDefaultConfiguration)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Bootstrapper.Run()
   at Honeywell.CIU888.Shell.App.Application_Startup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(UInt32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName, UInt32 flags)

anybody help in this.

Below is my code,

### BootStrapper.cs

```
public class BootStrapper : MefBootstrapper
{

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        base.InitializeShell();

        Application.Current.RootVisual = (UIElement)Shell;
    }

    protected override DependencyObject  CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.GetExportedValue<MainPage>();           
    }                    

    protected override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog()
    {            
        base.ConfigureAggregateCatalog();

        AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(this.GetType().Assembly));                    
    }

    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {

    }
}
```

### app.xaml.cs

public partial class App : Application
    {

```
    public App()
    {
        this.Startup += this.Application_Startup;
        this.Exit += this.Application_Exit;
        this.UnhandledException += this.Application_UnhandledException;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        //this.RootVisual = new MainPage();
        (new BootStrapper()).Run();
    }

    private void Application_Exit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        // If the app is running outside of the debugger then report the exception using
        // the browser's exception mechanism. On IE this will display it a yellow alert 
        // icon in the status bar and Firefox will display a script error.
        if (!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {

            // NOTE: This will allow the application to continue running after an exception has been thrown
            // but not handled. 
            // For production applications this error handling should be replaced with something that will 
            // report the error to the website and stop the application.
            e.Handled = true;
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate { ReportErrorToDOM(e); });                
        }
    }

    private void ReportErrorToDOM(ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string errorMsg = e.ExceptionObject.Message + e.ExceptionObject.StackTrace;
            errorMsg = errorMsg.Replace('"', '\'').Replace("\r\n", @"\n");

            System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Eval("throw new Error(\"Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application " + errorMsg + "\");");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

above Exception is coming if i call bootsrapper.run().

also i am running my project in "Elevated trust when running in browser" mode and signed xap file.

Answer (score 0):

["Security attributes need to be re-applied on types that derive from other types that also have security attributes"](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/464751/inheri)

Basically if you derive from a class that has security attributes applied (e.g. `[SecurityCritical]`, you must repeat those attributes on any overriding members/methods.

If you can provide the relevant code it will be easier to explain, but you can always use [DotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) to examine the code of the base classes (if you do not have the source handy) as that will show the attributes.

Comment: @Muthu: I notice all your overrides are `protected`. You should always ensure the overrides are the same as the parent class or you may hide something that Prism needs public access to.